# Don't find the package com.google.android.gms.games.request on google-play-services_lib

Tags: android, eclipse, google-play-services

I try to work with the google play API for my android project.
I need to use the BaseGameUtils. But the BaseGameUtils use the package **com.google.android.gms.games.request** and i don't find this package !
I work with eclipse, and my **google-play-services_lib** is on version 4242000.
Thank you !

---

I have solve my problem with updating googl-play-services_lib to the lastest version **4323000**

Comment: Google Play services out of date.  Requires 4323000 but found 3136130
I checked the google-play-library manifest and `android:versionCode="4323030"`so whats wrong ?